How to manage archived accounts in Google Workspace?
I am very new to the Google world and trying to get some automation done to see if the below would work in App-script. I am also not a Java guy, so I try my best. We use Okta as our SSO. Once a user account is suspended there, I want GWS to move the user from our main org to a sub org called 'Archive Users' Once they are moved there, Change the license from 'Google Workspace Enterprise Standard' to 'Google Workspace Enterprise Standard - Archived User' then change their status to Archived and wait 90 days then remove there account completely below is what I have pieced together let me know if I am going entirely in the wrong direction.
Archiving_users_GWS
function suspendAndArchiveUsers() {
  var mainOrgUsers = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: 'domain.com',
    query: 'orgUnitPath=/MainOrg and suspended=true'
  });

  if (mainOrgUsers.users && mainOrgUsers.users.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mainOrgUsers.users.length; i++) {
      var user = mainOrgUsers.users[i];
      
      // Move user to Archive organization
      AdminDirectory.Users.update({ orgUnitPath: '/Archived Users', userKey: user.primaryEmail });

      // Change license
      var licenses = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.listForProductAndSku('Google-Apps', '1010020026', { userId: user.primaryEmail });
      for (var j = 0; j < licenses.length; j++) {
        AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.remove(licenses[j].resourceId);
      }
      AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.insert({
        userId: user.primaryEmail,
        skuId: '1010340004'
      });

      // Record timestamp of move
      PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty(user.primaryEmail, new Date().getTime());
    }
  }
}

function deleteUsers() {
  var archiveOrgUsers = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: 'domain.com',
    query: 'orgUnitPath=/Archived Users'
  });

  if (archiveOrgUsers.users && archiveOrgUsers.users.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < archiveOrgUsers.users.length; i++) {
      var user = archiveOrgUsers.users[i];
      var movedTime = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty(user.primaryEmail);
      if (movedTime && (new Date().getTime() - parseInt(movedTime, 10) >= 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
        // Delete user after 90 days
        AdminDirectory.Users.remove(user.primaryEmail);
        PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteProperty(user.primaryEmail);
      }
    }
  }
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Regarding "I'm not a Java guy", please bear in mind that Google Apps Script allows end-users to write scripts using JavaScript, not Java. P.D. A long time ago I read that Google Apps Script uses Java internally but end-users don't have access to that only Google employees.

Regarding the script, please make a more specific query. Does it work? What happens or not happens when you run it?

Just use the Directory API to set the archived flag:
Users.update( { 
archived: true, 
orgUnitPath: '/Archived Users', 
userKey: user.primaryEmail
} )

No need to change the license directly.
